# Get historic market cap from yfinance

Tags: python, yahoo-finance, yfinance

I am using `yfinance` in order to automatically generate some financial overviews of different company stocks. The problem I am having is that the module does not seem to provide the market cap over time.

Is it possible to get historic data of the market cap of a stock using `yfinance`?

I have figured out how to get the current market cap

```
import yfinance as yf

ticker = yf.Ticker('AAPL')
current_market_cap = ticker.info['marketCap']
```

but not how to get it for e.g. the last 4 years. One can easily get the last 4 years of cash flow or financial data with

```
ticker.financials
ticker.cashflow
```

Alternatively, is there a better module other than `yfinance` to access this data from a python script?

Comment: See: [Fetch MarketCap historically #1008](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/issues/1008)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot query yfinance for this data, but you can calculate it from data that they provide, so long as you can stick to quarterly calculations.

You can gather the day that their quarterly statements are made by:

```
ticker = yf.Ticker('AAPL')
all_dates = ticker.quarterly_income_stmt.columns
```

And you could use those those dates to query for total shares (date will require reformatting that I did not want to take the time to do; manually its intuitive, just 'YYYY-MM-DD'):

```
total_shares = ticker.quarterly_income_stmt[date]['Basic Average Shares']
```

Then take the total shares, gather the stock price, and calculate for market cap by doing `total shares * stock price`:

```
stock_price = ticker.history(start='2023-09-26', end='2023-09-26')
market_cap = stock_price * total_shares
```

EDIT: just noticed your question about other modules. There are other modules, but you likely need to pay (and often have to pay quite a lot) for anything better than yfinance.

Comment: Ok thanks, this is what I was hoping for. Will try it out. One comment though for others ending up on this post, `ticker.history(start='2023-09-26', end='2023-09-26')` may return empty. E.g. if the date happens to be on a holiday, at least in my experience so far.

Comment: Ended up getting the number of shares through `ticker.financials.loc['Basic Average Shares']` where the yearly values are provided instead.

Comment: @rulf Okay, but be cautious with that number, as shares are often only accurate during quarterly updates. It may work fine for your purposes, but is far from accurate legally.